# How to add html code to the table column header in Eclipse RAP

Tags: swt, jface, eclipse-rap

I'm trying to add a div to the table column header, but this does not affected.

```java
TableColumn column = table.getColumn(columnIndex);
column.setData(RWT.MARKUP_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
column.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
column.setWidth(COLUMN_WIDTH);
column.setResizable(Boolean.FALSE);
column.setText("<div></div>");
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'does not affected'? How does the column look like and what do you expect?

Comment: @Rüdiger Herrmann It looks like simple text in browser.

Comment: Table columns (currently) don't support markup. How should the table columns look like? Maybe there is a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markup can only be applied to `TableItem`s. Table columns currently don't support markup.

If you think you have a valid use case, you may want to open an enhancement request here: https://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/